# Rhythmbox keeps putting itself back into the sound indicator

Tags: sound, indicator, rhythmbox, dconf

I am new to this forum and a relatively light linux user- so please be concise.

I have used dconf editor to blacklist 'rhythmbox.desktop' and 'rhythmbox'.
I have deleted it from the interested-media-players section.
I have tried them together and separately.
It goes away but after opening and then closing it, Rhytmbox is still present in the sound indicator even if I then immediately log out and in. The only way I can get it to go away again is to delete if from the blacklisted players, log out, log in, replace it into the blacklisted payers, log out, log in.

Is there a way to keep it from showing up in the indicator without deleting the program?

Comment: The dupe is about VLC, but the procedure is *exactly* the same.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I think it is worth leaving open since this got a good answer and people with a rhythmbox problem aren't going to look at vlc solutions.

Comment: @Seth, you're right! Retracted the vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If blacklisting doesn't work you can -

Open Rb > Tools > Plugins

Scroll down, find & disable the Mpris Dbus.. plugin, close Rb

Then in dconf editor remove rhythmbox.desktop from interested-media-players, a log out/in may then be required, may not.